# How to send a video in multiple partsusing React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multithreading

Actually I have misunderstanding connected with big video uploading to the server. I do not want to use AWS S3, but I want my program to split video into smaller parts(chunks) and after that send to the base. In other words I want large video to be provided to the server, via small parts.

I am using React js for front end and node js(express js) for backend. My server is local. Which are the technologies that I can use for this task ? I googled a lot, however didn't find anything helpful.